# Is it ok if I put the slogan for a website banner without articles or should I put them as below:

Tags: articles, definite-articles, indefinite-articles, slogan

From (an) idea to (a) successful startup within 1 month!

Comment: That sounds more like a legal question than a linguistic one.

Comment: Consider a similar phrase: *from (the) start to (the) finish*. As a matter of English usage, both articles can be dropped in both. *Why* they are not necessary is another matter - and perhaps a more interesting one. You might like to edit your question to address that instead :) .

Comment: Idiomatically, ***from start to finish*** is far more common than ***from the start to the finish***, but [both versions occur](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=from+idea+to%2Cfrom+an+idea+to+a&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cfrom%20idea%20to%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cfrom%20an%20idea%20to%20a%3B%2Cc0). It's just a stylistic choice.

Comment: @Helmar How is it a legal question? In which countries does the law control the wording on website banners?

Comment: You can treat it as a "title", or words on a sign.  Search around and you will find these topics discussed in significant detail.

Comment: @TrevorD, a banner is an official way to market someone's business. If the advertisement doesn't match the product it can get a legal matter very fast. Since the OP wants to use it on a website banner that does seem to apply.

Comment: @Helmar Correct - but that legal situation is not changed by the presence or absence of the two articles "an" & "a", which is what this Q. is about. So whether to include "an/a" is **not** a legal Q..

Comment: @TrevorD actually the missing articles make it less prone for legal actions. Since it isn't a full sentence anymore and it gives more room for interpretation. It isn't clear anymore it even refers to a service or just retells the story of the marketer itself.

Comment: @Helmar Are you a lawyer?  If so, in which country/jurisdiction?

Comment: @TrevorD No I am not, it just reminds me of an example case that was discussed in an elective introductory semester regarding marketing in the EU I took a long time ago. The jist of it was more or less that as long as it is clearly a attention grabbing slogan the content is not as important. If it can be considered a factual statement, then you have to be careful. After all there is a reason marketing ads are vetted by legal departments in most companies.

Comment: Actually, there is a difference in meaning between the two alternatives.  But since the question is closed I suppose it's not worth pursuing.

Answer (score 2):

This is an opinion-based answer, so may be shot down, but I do build web sites.

The omission of the indefinite article is common usage in English titles and slogans, whether or not it is ungrammatical. As an example, when I did a Google search for “From mouse to man” I got eight hits on the first page (most in a scientific context), whereas when I searched for “From a mouse to a man” I got none. Not quite the ad slogan, but I’m sure I’ve seen things like “From weakling to superman in twenty-four hours!” Also, the popular phrase [“From hero to zero”](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/from-hero-to-zero).

A banner slogan of the type you quote needs to be as snappy as possible so it *demands* the omission of the articles.

But note that [normal English style](http://www.grammarbook.com/numbers/numbers.asp) would require you to spell out the numeral ‘1’ either as ‘one’ or ‘a’. Although you can break this rule for slogans (I’d certainly use ‘24 hours’ in my example above) I think that in this slogan the numeral ‘1’ would look odd. I would use the longer ‘one’ as it provides more visual emphasis for what is a key word, and you can add even more emphasis with italics or colour if you wish.

Comment: Opinion-based perhaps, but it is good opinion and a useful answer.

Comment: you're already departing from 'normal English style' by proposing the omission of the articles - thus using 'headline/slogan' style - so 'normal English style' no longer applies, and hence the "1" can be used as a numeral for brevity of the slogan (e.g. if space is a consideration).

Comment: @TrevorD — I understand that, and thought had made that clear, and would always recommend 24 hours, rather than "twenty-four". But my point is that '1' is unusual in these circumstances, and the reader would sense it without even identifying the cause. There is no need to shorten 1 to one for space, and the reason advertisers would use it is because it is an important part of the pitch (one rather than twelve) and needs visibility. You can italicize it for even greater emphasis, which with a numeral might just be taken as type style.

Comment: I've just modified my answer a little to provide a supporting illustration and incorporate some of the points into the answer that I made in my comment replying to @TrevorD.